# Woocommerce cart - Split into sections and send as one order based on user preferences

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a feeling what i'm after isn't doable within Woocommerce but i thought i'd come here in case anyone has already done it or knows of a plugin which can help.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is for the user to go onto the site and to be shown a list of checkboxes. These checkboxes would be: Section A, Section B, Section C etc. The user would select one and then would be able to add products into the cart. These products selected fall into a section called 'Section A' on the cart page.

I then want the user to be prompted with a pop up asking to either select another Section, for example, Section B or continue to checkout. If they select another section, the process would repeat and they would be able to select products again. These products would instead fall under a heading called 'Section B' in the cart page.

The user could end up adding different products into multiple sections but in the end the overall cart would be combined. So in effect they would end up with an order like this:

**Section A**

Product 1  £10.99 qty: 2

Product 2  £15.99 qty: 3

Product 2  £15.99 qty: 2

**Section B**

Product 1  £10.99 qty: 2

Product 2  £15.99 qty: 3

Product 5  £7.99 qty: 2

etc

Is there anything out there which can help me achieve this?

Many thanks,
Shaun